# App store preview says app is localized to various languages but it is only in English

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

App store preview of my app says it's available in various languages.

However it wasn't ever localized. In iTunes Connect I only see English as primary language (and dropdown menu is empty), and also there's no .lproj files for different languages in Xcode project.

What can be the issue? I only want my app to be available in English and wish App Store Preview to indicate this.

Below are screenshots of App Store preview and Xcode info

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using any third part libraries which may contain localizations?

Answer (score 0):

This Language might be set in your iTunes Connect at time you uploaded to App store.

Comment: I think this answer is guiding you in the right direction. Go to iTunes Connect and have a look at the languages there. (Navigate to your app's general info page)